# Blackberry: Blocking outgoing SMS

Tags: blackberry, sms

Is there a way to block outgoing SMS on blackberry?

I know the OutboundMessageListener interface allows you to get a notification when a message is sent, but at that point the message has already been sent. I need to figure out if there's a way to actually block the device from sending a text message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible on JDE >= 4.6.0 using the net.rim.blackberry.api.sms.SendListener interface. Here's more info: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blocking-outgoing-SMS/m-p/709091#M138032

Answer (score 0):

RIM do have a corporate server solution for setting inbound/outbound restrictions on calls/texts etc called BES. However, that does require the handset you want to set a policy on to be associated with your BES server.

http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB11004&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_SUPPORTISSUE_1_1&dialogID=86224048&stateId=1%200%2086220830